# .htaccess WordPress ignore directory and remove index.php from that directory

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I know how to tell WordPress how to ignore a directory using the .htaccess file but I want to be able to remove the index.php from inside that directory too so I can access like this:

wordpresssite/directory/controller/function = wordpresssite/directory/`index.php/`controller/function

I've been trying but I'm clearly not very good at writing .htaccess files.

Thanks

**My .htaccess file**
The wordpress site is called smartronic and the subdirectory I want to ignore and remove index.php from is /mailin

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /smartronic/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(mailin|mailin/.*)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /smartronic/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

At the moment going to smartronic/mailin takes me to the xampp root page or a 404 page

Comment: Can we see your current htaccess file

Comment: @rosscooperdesign I don't really understand your requirement. What is the URL in the browser and what should it be rewritten to?

Comment: The url in browser should be smartronic/mailin/controller which should rewrite to smartronic/mailin/index.php/controller

Answer (score 0):

To insert `index.php` into a fixed URL, you can use a simple [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteRule ^mailin/controller /mailin/index.php/controller [L]
```

If `controller` is variable, you need to capture this part with `(...)` and append it after the substitution with `$1`

```
RewriteRule ^mailin/(.*)$ /mailin/index.php/$1 [L]
```